# VB.Net Grid View

Tags: vb.net, gridview, vb6, vb6-migration

I am working on VB.Net project in which I need to convert VB6.0 code to VB.Net. While converting I got to know that in VB6 in a `GridView` there is an event called `BeforeUpdate` which is not available in VB.Net. So please give me the alternative for this, which can do the same as `BeforeUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to take a look at the [CellValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.100).aspx) event, which happens before the content of the cell is updated.

You will be able to check the new value, modify it or cancel the modifications.